# Swift iOS doesRelativeDateFormatting have different values besides "Today" and "Yesterday"?

Tags: ios, date, swift, nsdateformatter, relative-date

I have a number of dates that I am trying to represent using a relative date such as "Today, Yesterday, 1 week ago, 1 month ago" etc...

This is the Swift code I am using:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
let uploadDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

Only "Today" and "Yesterday" are represented and the rest of the dates appear like the below:
Nov 24, 2014
Nov 17, 2014
etc...

Is there another way to represent all the dates using relative dating instead of the actual dates?

Comment: You mean like "2 days ago", "1 week ago" ?

Comment: https://github.com/melvitax/AFDateHelper This github repo has a good relative date function that you could edit to suit your projects. Hope that helps!

Comment: @MikeTaverne Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 26):

edit/Update: **Xcode 8.3.2 • Swift 3.1**

It is really easy if you use extensions and Calendar methods to help you with your calendrical calculations:

```
extension Date {
    var yearsFromNow: Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: self, to: Date()).year!
    }
    var monthsFromNow: Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: self, to: Date()).month!
    }
    var weeksFromNow: Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: self, to: Date()).weekOfYear!
    }
    var daysFromNow: Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: Date()).day!
    }
    var isInYesterday: Bool {
        return Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(self)
    }
    var hoursFromNow: Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: self, to: Date()).hour!
    }
    var minutesFromNow: Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: self, to: Date()).minute!
    }
    var secondsFromNow: Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: self, to: Date()).second!
    }
    var relativeTime: String {
        if yearsFromNow > 0 { return "\(yearsFromNow) year" + (yearsFromNow > 1 ? "s" : "") + " ago" }
        if monthsFromNow > 0 { return "\(monthsFromNow) month" + (monthsFromNow > 1 ? "s" : "") + " ago" }
        if weeksFromNow > 0 { return "\(weeksFromNow) week" + (weeksFromNow > 1 ? "s" : "") + " ago" }
        if isInYesterday { return "Yesterday" }
        if daysFromNow > 0 { return "\(daysFromNow) day" + (daysFromNow > 1 ? "s" : "") + " ago" }
        if hoursFromNow > 0 { return "\(hoursFromNow) hour" + (hoursFromNow > 1 ? "s" : "") + " ago" }
        if minutesFromNow > 0 { return "\(minutesFromNow) minute" + (minutesFromNow > 1 ? "s" : "") + " ago" }
        if secondsFromNow > 0 { return secondsFromNow < 15 ? "Just now"
            : "\(secondsFromNow) second" + (secondsFromNow > 1 ? "s" : "") + " ago" }
        return ""
    }
}
```

**Testing**

```
let calendar =  Calendar.current

let date1 = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: 2016, month:  3, day: 14, hour: 22, minute: 39).date!
let date2 = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: 2019, month:  4, day: 18, hour: 22, minute: 39).date!
let date3 = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: 2019, month: 6, day:  2, hour: 12, minute: 38).date!
let date4 = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: 2019, month: 6, day:  14, hour: 3, minute: 0).date!
let date5 = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: 2019, month: 6, day:  17, hour: 23, minute: 45).date!
let date6 = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: 2019, month: 6, day:  18, hour: 19, minute:  17).date!
let timeOffset1 = date1.relativeTime // "3 years ago"
let timeOffset2 = date2.relativeTime // "1 month ago"
let timeOffset3 = date3.relativeTime // "2 weeks ago"
let timeOffset4 = date4.relativeTime // "4 days ago"
let timeOffset5 = date5.relativeTime // "Yesterday"
let timeOffset6 = date6.relativeTime // "Just now"
```

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` is very thoroughly internationalized/localized. (For example, you only get today/yesterday/tomorrow in English, but other languages have words for other relative dates — おととい and 明後日 in Japanese, for example — and Apple's class uses them. (`NSDateComponentsFormatter` is very well localized for handling time/date intervals, too.) If you do something like this, you're shifting the burden of handling all sorts of international date/time formatting issues from Apple to yourself.

Comment: Very nice solution until support for <iOS 13 is no longer needed.

Answer (score 8):

iOS 13+ now has [RelativeDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/relativedatetimeformatter)

For examples: https://nshipster.com/formatter/#relativedatetimeformatter

```
let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
formatter.localizedString(from: DateComponents(day: 1, hour: 1)) // "in 1 day"
formatter.localizedString(from: DateComponents(day: -1)) // "1 day ago"
```

or

```
formatter.localizedString(for: date, relativeTo: Date())
```

Answer (score 6):

You should have a look at Mattt Thompsons Blog post about NSDateComponentsFormatter

http://nshipster.com/nsdatecomponents/
and
http://nshipster.com/nsformatter/

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .Full

let components = NSDateComponents()
components.day = 1
components.hour = 2

let string = formatter.stringFromDateComponents(components)
// 1 day, 2 hours
```

Example (by Mattt Thompson)

Answer (score 0):

```
var relativeTime: String {
    // don't forget spacing on these constants.
    let futurePrefix = "" // " in" is a viable choice here...
    let pastSuffix = " ago" // " ago" is a viable choice here...
    let now = NSDate()
    for (method, unitName) in [
        (now.years, "year"),
        (now.months, "month"),
        (now.weeks, "week"),
        (now.days, "day"),
        (now.hours, "hour"),
        (now.minutes, "minute"),
        (now.seconds, "second")
    ] {
        let qty = method(self)
        let absQty = abs(method(self))
        if absQty > 0 {
            return (qty < 0 ? futurePrefix : "") +
                String(absQty) + " " +
                unitName +
                (absQty == 1 ? "": "s") +
                (qty > 0 ? pastSuffix : "")
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

An alternative implementation of Leo Dabus's implementation of relativeTime that does both future and past and is more succinct. (Swift2.3)