# why the date is always today though i am passing different date

Tags: ios, swift

this is my code

```
 let dateValue = formatterDate.dateFromString(request.date)
        print("da = \(request.date)")
        let dayValue = NSDate()
        let compnentsDate = myCalendar.components(.Year, fromDate: dateValue!)
        let componentsDay = myCalendar.components(.Year, fromDate: dayValue)
        if compnentsDate.year == componentsDay.year && compnentsDate.month == componentsDay.month && compnentsDate.day  == componentsDay.day {
            cell.dateLabel.text = "today"
        }else {
            if compnentsDate.year == componentsDay.year && compnentsDate.month == componentsDay.month && compnentsDate.day  == (componentsDay.day + 1 ){
            cell.dateLabel.text = "tomorrow"
            }else {
                cell.dateLabel.text = request.date
            }

        }
```

as you see I am making print, and the value of the print is:

```
da = Jan, 25, 2016
```

However, the code always goes to the first if statement, and tell me "today"

why please?

what is wrong in my code?

Comment: NSCalendar has a method called isDateInToday http://stackoverflow.com/a/34441658/2303865

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify all of the components you need when you call the `components:fromDate:` function.

You need to pass `.Year`, `.Month`, and `.Day`, not just `.Year`. Something like this:

```
let compnentsDate = myCalendar.components([.Year , .Month , .Day], fromDate: dateValue!)
let componentsDay = myCalendar.components([.Year , .Month , .Day], fromDate: dayValue)
```

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. I just did a search and found that. You beat me to it.